# What happens at compile time when you try to cast a LinkedList to a LinkedList<String>?

Tags: java, generics, casting

In the following, I get a runtime exception on line 5, not on line 4. What is that cast actually doing?
Any insight or links to relevant reading would be awesome.

```
List list = new LinkedList();
list.add(new Date());
list.add("Hello");
List<String> list2 = (List<String>)list;
String value = list2.get(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is that cast actually doing?

Nothing, at execution time. That's why you'll get a warning saying that it's an *unchecked cast* - it's not really checking anything, because the object itself (at execution time) has no concept of being a `List<String>` - it's just a list. If you had:

```
Object x = ...;
List<String> list = (List<String>) x;
```

then that would check that `x` refers to a list of *some* kind... but it wouldn't check the "stringness" of the list.

This is the way Java generics works, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

The compiler checks generics before erasing them. So something like:

```
final List<String> strings = ...
strings.add(new Date());
```

Would be picked up at compile time.

Once the generics are checked, the compiler erases them, this is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  So at execution time generics do not exist.

So, the cast:

```
final List list = new LinkedList();
final List<String> list2 = (List<String>)list;
```

Actually does *nothing* as the compiler can only check that `list` is a `List`, which it is. It does not check the contents.

The compiler will, however, warn you about the lack of type checking here:

```
unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.List
unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.List
unchecked cast
  required: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
  found:    java.util.List
```

The first two warnings relate to adding items it a `List` of an unknown type - this is because you can do the reverse, which will cause problems at run time:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
List raw = strings;
```

The third warning is about the unsafe conversion from `List` to `List<String>`.

In fact you can even do this (although I don't recommend that you do):

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
List<Date> dates = (List<Date>) (List) strings;
```

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer. I can only accept one though, so I went for the one with more upvotes.